# Visual Studio 2017 - Nuget 3.5.0 - Modernizr.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modernizr

I was tasked with updating Modernizr to the latest version 3.5.0 for Visual Studio ASP.NET applications via Nuget and after the install roughly 52 files were installed -

**Name of File**

- addTest.js
- atRule.js
- contains.js
- computedStyle.js
- createElement.js
- cssomPrefixes.js
- cssToDOM.js
- docElement.js
- domPrefixes.js
- domToCSS.js
- fnBind.js
- generate.js
- getBody.js
- hasEvent.js
- hasOwnProp.js
- html5printshiv.js
- html5shiv.js
- injectElementWithStyles.js
- inputElem.js
- is.js
- isSVG.js
- load.js
- modElem.js
- Modernizr.js
- ModernizrProto.js
- mq.js
- nativeTestProps.js
- omPrefixes.js
- prefixed.js
- prefixedCSS.js
- prefixedCSSValue.js
- prefixes.js
- roundedEquals.js
- setClasses.js
- slice.js
- testAllProps.js
- testDOMProps.js
- testProp.js
- testPropsAll.js
- testRunner.js
- testStyles.js
- testXhrType.js
- toStringFn.js

This resulsted in creating a bundle -

```
        //JavaScript Shared
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/addTest.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/atRule.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/atRule.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/contains.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/computedStyle.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/createElement.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/cssomPrefixes.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/cssToDOM.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/docElement.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/domPrefixes.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/domToCSS.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/fnBind.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/generate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/getBody.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/hasEvent.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/hasOwnProp.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/html5printshiv.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/html5shiv.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/injectElementWithStyles.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/inputElem.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/is.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/isSVG.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/load.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/modElem.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/Modernizr.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/ModernizrProto.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/mq.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/nativeTestProps.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/omPrefixes.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/prefixed.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/prefixedCSS.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/prefixedCSSValue.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/prefixes.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/roundedEquals.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/setClasses.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/slice.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testAllProps.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testDOMProps.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testProp.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testPropsAll.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testRunner.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testStyles.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/testXhrType.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr/toStringFn.js"
                   ));



 at Modernizr.js:1 (anonymous) @ Modernizr.js:1
```

In the `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

Line of Code `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`

Error:

```
Modernizr.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Modernizr.js:1
(anonymous) @ Modernizr.js:1
ModernizrProto.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at ModernizrProto.js:1
(anonymous) @ ModernizrProto.js:1
addTest.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at addTest.js:1
(anonymous) @ addTest.js:1
atRule.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at atRule.js:1
(anonymous) @ atRule.js:1
contains.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at contains.js:1
(anonymous) @ contains.js:1
computedStyle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at computedStyle.js:1
(anonymous) @ computedStyle.js:1
createElement.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at createElement.js:1
(anonymous) @ createElement.js:1
cssomPrefixes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at cssomPrefixes.js:1
(anonymous) @ cssomPrefixes.js:1
cssToDOM.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at cssToDOM.js:1
(anonymous) @ cssToDOM.js:1
docElement.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at docElement.js:1
(anonymous) @ docElement.js:1
domPrefixes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at domPrefixes.js:1
(anonymous) @ domPrefixes.js:1
domToCSS.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at domToCSS.js:1
(anonymous) @ domToCSS.js:1
fnBind.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at fnBind.js:1
(anonymous) @ fnBind.js:1
generate.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at generate.js:1
(anonymous) @ generate.js:1
getBody.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at getBody.js:1
(anonymous) @ getBody.js:1
hasEvent.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at hasEvent.js:1
(anonymous) @ hasEvent.js:1
hasOwnProp.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at hasOwnProp.js:1
(anonymous) @ hasOwnProp.js:1
html5printshiv.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at html5printshiv.js:1
(anonymous) @ html5printshiv.js:1
html5shiv.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at html5shiv.js:1
(anonymous) @ html5shiv.js:1
injectElementWithStyles.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at injectElementWithStyles.js:1
(anonymous) @ injectElementWithStyles.js:1
inputElem.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at inputElem.js:1
(anonymous) @ inputElem.js:1
is.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at is.js:1
(anonymous) @ is.js:1
isSVG.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at isSVG.js:1
(anonymous) @ isSVG.js:1
load.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at load.js:1
(anonymous) @ load.js:1
modElem.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at modElem.js:1
(anonymous) @ modElem.js:1
mq.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at mq.js:1
(anonymous) @ mq.js:1
nativeTestProps.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at nativeTestProps.js:1
(anonymous) @ nativeTestProps.js:1
omPrefixes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at omPrefixes.js:1
(anonymous) @ omPrefixes.js:1
prefixed.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at prefixed.js:1
(anonymous) @ prefixed.js:1
prefixedCSS.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at prefixedCSS.js:1
(anonymous) @ prefixedCSS.js:1
prefixedCSSValue.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at prefixedCSSValue.js:1
(anonymous) @ prefixedCSSValue.js:1
prefixes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at prefixes.js:1
(anonymous) @ prefixes.js:1
roundedEquals.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at roundedEquals.js:1
(anonymous) @ roundedEquals.js:1
setClasses.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at setClasses.js:1
(anonymous) @ setClasses.js:1
slice.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at slice.js:1
(anonymous) @ slice.js:1
testAllProps.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testAllProps.js:1
(anonymous) @ testAllProps.js:1
testDOMProps.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testDOMProps.js:1
(anonymous) @ testDOMProps.js:1
testProp.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testProp.js:1
(anonymous) @ testProp.js:1
testPropsAll.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testPropsAll.js:1
(anonymous) @ testPropsAll.js:1
testRunner.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testRunner.js:1
(anonymous) @ testRunner.js:1
testStyles.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testStyles.js:1
(anonymous) @ testStyles.js:1
testXhrType.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at testXhrType.js:1
(anonymous) @ testXhrType.js:1
toStringFn.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at toStringFn.js:1
(anonymous) @ toStringFn.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

After Modernizr version 2.8.3, Modernizr Nuget package stopped being upgraded.  The problem is the client I am working for is very secure and the a la cart build your Modernizr and download from the Web is a NO NO.  Reverted from version 3.5.0 back to 2.8.3.   Nothing wrong with current Modernizr, just cannot build out they way the site has it built.  Problem Solved.  (Learning Curve) I know Modernizr now.